# How to implement email adapter for Parse to allow password reset feature

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, parse-server, mailgun, bitnami

**Problem description**

I am using AWS EC2 to host my bitnami parse server which acts as the backend for my android app. I am having trouble implementing password reset for the users of my app. I have followed the instructions from:

- https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server#email-verification-and-password-reset

But I still get the error:

*"com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for password reset and email verification functionality."*

**Step by step of what I did**

1. I went to mailgun and created an account.
2. I registered a domain that I own (hosted by squarespace) to mailgun. (see picture below)

[image]

3. I went to my server.js file located in the apps/parse/htdocs folder.
4. I modified my server.js file to look like this, shown below.

[image]

5. Then in my android application, I called a test password reset using the following code.

[image]

**Things I am unsure of**

1. I haven't physically installed anything such as the simple-mailgun-adapter. I tried to follow this link: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter. and install 
   *npm install --save @parse/simple-mailgun-adapter* to my apps/parse/htdocs folder. But I got a whole bunch of errors. Shown below.

[image]

2. I'm not sure what the publicServerURL is in the server.js file. I assumed it is the same thing as serverURL, so if you look at my server.js file, both serverURL and publicServerURL have the same input.

Please let me know if you guys can spot any errors I made. I've been working on this for a week, and still can't get password recovery working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. If your package.json has

> "parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter":"1.0.0",

under the dependencies section, then the package should be installed automatically.  I usually check under the node_modules folder.

2. The resetPassword error is saying you are missing the appName parameter.  You need to add it to your server config object:

> ```
> var config = { 
>     ...
>     publicServerURL: (process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337') + mountPath,
>     // Your apps name. This will appear in the subject and body of the emails that are sent.
>     appName: 'YOURAPPNAME', 
>     ...
> ```

3. Your publicServerURL is usually something like server.domain.com.  It helps since people resetting their password will be redirected to a webpage on the domain where they will enter a new password.  It's nice for users if the domain reflects something they can trust...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add `{}` in your package.json as it should not be empty.